# Allow access to one URL with username/password and others from IP address

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following with Spring Security:

I need to allow outside access on a certain endpoint, at `/webhooks/`, but protect it with a HTTP basic username/password. On all other endpoints, access must be restricted, except from certain subnets.

Here's what I have thus far. It's not working, as everything gets denied.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * Created on 27 July 2016 @ 1:49 PM
 * Component for project "security"
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:/test.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${test.webhooks.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${test.webhooks.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()

                        .antMatchers("/webhooks/").authenticated()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress("10.0.0.0/8")
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress("172.16.0.0/16")
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress("192.168.1.0/24")
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress("172.0.0.0/8")
                        .antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
        ;

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser(username).password(password).roles("WEBHOOKS_ACCESS")
        ;
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome! I'm not sure if the chained ant matchers are correct in any event.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out how to do this. Not sure if this is the "spring way" or whatever, but it seems to work. Any suggestions are welcome.

So my new class looks as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * Created on 27 July 2016 @ 1:49 PM
 * Component for project "security"
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:/security.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.webhooks.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${security.webhooks.password}")
    private String password;

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebHookSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)  throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/webhooks/")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().hasRole("WEBHOOKS_ACCESS")
                        .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                        .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class InternalSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .access("hasIpAddress('10.0.0.0/8') or hasIpAddress('172.16.0.0/16') or hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24') or hasIpAddress('172.0.0.0/8') or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')")
            ;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser(username).password(password).roles("WEBHOOKS_ACCESS")
        ;
    }
}
```

Which I derived from [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity). Hope this helps someone!